# crystal reports month date range for earnings

Tags: date, crystal-reports

My client has a report that accepts a date range to get a report showing projected revenue. So, a user would enter a date range of '1/1/2015 to 1/31/2015' and the report should return data only in the range '1/1/2015 to 1/31/2015 grouped by week. I am instead for the week of 12/29/2014 (which 1/1/2015 fall into) and 2/1/2015 (which 1/31/2015 falls into). The report is intended to group by week, but I do not want days on the report that are earlier than the start date parameter or later than the end date parameter.

The sql statement for this report is:

```
SELECT job.job, job.status, job.customer_po, job.part_number,     job.unit_price, 
job.price_uofm, delivery.promiseddate, delivery.remaining_quantity,     job.build_to_stock, job.description, job.make_quantity, job.pick_quantity,     job.shipped_quantity, job.lead_days
FROM dbo.delivery as delivery RIGHT OUTER JOIN db.job as job on delivery.job     = job.job
WHERE job.build_to_stock = 0 AND (job.status = 'active' OR job.status =   'hold' OR job.status = 'pending')
```

The date range is from this code and parameters:

```
Max – Maximum(?Date Range)
Min – Minimun(?Date Range)
Date Range - "From " & {@Min} & " to " & {@Max}
```

This is the group expression

```
Group 2 Name - GroupName ({@Adj Date 2}, "weekly") & " thru " & cdate(GroupName ({@Adj Date 2}, "weekly"))+6
```

This is the select expression

```
{@Date} = {?Date Range} and
not {Job.Build_To_Stock} and
{Job.Status} in ["Active", "Hold", "Pending"]
```

Do you know how I can prevent the "overflow" of dates outside of date range?

Thx

Comment: Please post your record selection formula.

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes and I will edit my post

Comment: Sorry, i did not get it. The problem is the group title? Is the data ok? What does the report show and what did you expected?

Comment: @Ryan I added more details

Comment: @heringer I added more details in regards to your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have date filtering in your record selection formula there will not be any "overflow" outside of that range. If you've got `{Record.Date} in Minimum({?DateRange}) to Maximum({?DateRange})`, which it sounds like you do, then your report will not contain any records outside of the parameter regardless of how you group them.

Your problem might stem from over-complicating or misinterpreting the grouping. All you need to do is group by `{Record.Date}` and select "Group by week" in the grouping options... you don't need any complicated formulas to break it out by week. But be aware that the way weeks are referred to is by their starting date. For example, if you had a record with a date of Feb. 19, 2015, that record would fall into the group labeled "Feb. 15, 2015" even if your {?DateRange} parameter was Feb. 18 - Feb. 15.